# WPF - Tab to work inside of textbox - not for selection another ui elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Iam creating custom date textbox and I want behavior of it (doing that in code-behind):

On focus, it sets the text to current DateTime, format: dd.MM.yyyy and selects the "dd" part. (t.SelectionStart = 0, t.SelectionLength = 2).

Then I want to press tab to change selection to "MM" part. ( t.SelectionStart = 3; t.SelectionLength = 2;)

*["t" is current TextBox]*

**Code I have:**

```
    private void DateTextBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            if(t.SelectionStart == 0)
            {
                t.SelectionStart = 3; t.SelectionLength = 2;
            } else if(t.SelectionStart == 3)
            {
                t.SelectionStart = 6; t.SelectionLength = 4;
            } else
            {
                t.SelectionStart = 0; t.SelectionLength = 2;
            }
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

Tried e.Handled false and true. Nothing changed.

Now it behaves like:
Iam on previous control (TextBox too), press Tab, focus goes to this TextBox, another event sets the selection for the first two character, press Tab again, focus goes on next UIelement.

How to force Tab to work only in this TextBox as soon as focus gets there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, change the PreviewKeyUp to PreviewKeyDown and it works.
Tab press down action triggered the UI to focus next uielement before the PreviewKeyUp event could trigger.